# Python, reading files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am studying how to use files in Python (read() and readlines() methods). Now I am trying to access concrete elements using these methods. I would like to know what is the difference between accessing with square and round brackets. I know that indexing is going with square brackets, but what about round? Why the result looks so? And what method do you recommend for using more? Thanks for the help.

The file:

Awake! For Morning In the Bowl of Night
Has flung the Stone that puts the Stars to Flight:
And Lo! the Hunter of the East has caught
The Sultan's Turret in a Noose of Light!

```
new = '/Users/tt/Desktop/omar.py'
poem = open(new, 'r')
lines = poem.read()
lines[0]
'A'
lines[1]
'w'
poem.close()


new = '/Users/tt/Desktop/omar.py'
poem = open(new, 'r')
poem.read(0)
''
poem.read(1)
'A'
poem.read(2)
'wa'
poem.read(3)
'ke!'
poem.close()

new = '/Users/tt/Desktop/omar.py'
poem = open(new, 'r')
poem.readlines(0)
['Awake! For Morning In the Bowl of Night\n', 'Has flung the Stone that puts the Stars to 
Flight:\n', 'And Lo! the Hunter of the East has caught\n', "The Sultan's Turret in a Noose of 
Light!\n"]
poem.readlines(1)
[]
poem.readlines(2)
[]
poem.close()

new = '/Users/tt/Desktop/omar.py'
poem = open(new, 'r')
poem.readlines(1)
['Awake! For Morning In the Bowl of Night\n']
poem.readlines(2)
['Has flung the Stone that puts the Stars to Flight:\n']
poem.close()


new = '/Users/tt/Desktop/omar.py'
poem = open(new, 'r')
lines = poem.readlines()
lines[0]
'Awake! For Morning In the Bowl of Night\n'
lines[1]
'Has flung the Stone that puts the Stars to Flight:\n'
poem.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

As briefly explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp), if an integer is provided as an argument of `read(n)`, the file-reader only reads the first `n` characters of the file.

If you first `read()` everything, then the whole input is stored in memory. If you then access the read object by doing

```
lines = poem.read()
lines[0]
```

then you essentially just pick the first element from the stored sequence, but you do have the whole sequence in memory.

So, essentially, I would recommend using the square brackets syntax most of the times if the input files are not that big, as it can remove some confusion in accessing the fields. However, if you, for example, scan through thousands of files and you know that you need just the first line or the first 10 characters, then by all means use the `read(n)` notation.

Hope this intuition helps!